# I need to dynamic insert post containing javascript from my other website?

Tags: wp-insert-post

I am trying to dynamicly add some content post (also containing some js), but the javascript part is filter out. I thought by using wp_set_current_user the js would be included.

This is my main function which generate the post

```
   function mydomain_which_page2($atts) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'temp_title' => 'something'
    ), $atts ) );
        //post exists?
    if( wp_exist_post_by_title( $temp_title ) ) {
        $redirect_title = sanitize_title( $temp_title);
        header('Location:' . $redirect_title);
        exit();
    } else { 
        // post does not exist
        wp_set_current_user(NULL, 'Test user');
        //GET THE MAPS
        $output = getIncludeContent('myotherdomain.com/generate.php'); 
        //SAVE AS WP POSTS
        mydomain_add_post($temp_title,$output);
        //REDIRECT
        $redirect_title = sanitize_title( $temp_title);
        header('Location:' . $redirect_title);
        exit();
    }   
}
```

directly going to myotherdomain.com/generate.php will output the js in source code also $output will show the source code with js.
and add_post function

```
function add_post($title, $content){
    // Create post object wp_strip_all_tags
    //$content = strip_tags($content);

    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => $title,
      'post_content'  => $content,
      'post_name'   => sanitize_title($title),
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => array(1)
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post ); 
}
```

Any tips, suggestions?

regards

Comment: Exactly what works and what doesn't in that code? Where does it fail?

Comment: if fails posting the javascript which is generated on my other website. I think i found a solution see my answer

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a solution

```
function add_post($title, $content){
    // Create post object wp_strip_all_tags

    if (!is_user_logged_in()){
        $user_id = 1;
        wp_set_current_user($user_id,$user_login);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
        do_action('wp_login',$user_login);
    }

    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => $title,
      'post_content'  => $content,
      'post_name'   => sanitize_title($title),
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
     // 'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => array(1)
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post ); 
}
```

Comment: `$user_login` is never set to a value. You should be seeing a PHP warning when the user is not logged in.